# About 64 bit and 32 bit JVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am writing a JAVA program calling dll functions with JNI. In order to load the library I may need to install 32-bit JVM on my 64-bit machine. However, no matter what I installed (even those which are supposed to be installed on 32-bit system), eclipse always indicates that it is 64 bit.

Do you guys know how to fix that?

Millions of thanks~

Comment: Which version of eclipse do you have? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: How does Eclipse "indicate" that? Do you mean Help->About->Installation Details->Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

For manually configuring JVM you need to edit the eclipse.ini file.

Have a look at here

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

This one worked for me.

But As you are using JNI. There may be some issue with 32 bit and 64 bit dll.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I specified the JVM to be the "32-bit" one I downloaded. But it still can not load the library indicating "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"

Answer (score 0):

the .dll should have some native code. IA-32 bit means Intel architecture. So it should not be loaded in a AMD 64 bit platform. you should try to make the .dll compatible for AMD -64 bit platform. Try some cross compiler.